# Refresh page every 5 secs in Protractor until element is present

Tags: protractor, uiveri5

Scenario: I am working with Protractor testing framework and I need to refresh the page every 5 seconds until the element is present on the web page but I am not sure how to do it.

I have seen protractor documentation and I have come across this page https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions even this doesn't refresh the page

```
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var ele = element(by.control({controlType: "sap.m.ObjectIdentifier", id: /clone/, 
    properties: {text: "MANAGER"}}));
    var isVisible = EC.visibilityOfElementLocated(ele);
    browser.wait(isVisible, 5000); //wait for an element to become visible
    browser.sleep(3000)
```

**Any suggestions**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `browser.refresh()` in a loop:

```
while(true) {
   if(/*element not visible */) {
     browser.refresh();
   } else {
     break;
   }
   browser.sleep(5000);
 }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.